# How to put maven project version in war file manifest?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

I need to have Maven insert the version number from the POM file into the manifest located in the WAR file under /WEB-INF/manifest.mf.

How do I do this? I was able to easily file documentation for doing this in a JAR file using the maven-jar-plugin, but that does not work on a WAR file.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Figured it out using the maven-war-plugin. See the configuration below:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.1</version>
     <configuration>
         <archive>
             <manifestEntries>
                 <version>${project.version}</version>
             </manifestEntries>
         </archive>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If you're interested in reading such versioning info via web URL too, for instance at `http://example.com/versioninfo.txt` you can filter a `versioninfo.txt` template, which contains your`${project.version}`, and [include the version file into the war](http://www.taringamberini.com/en/howto/java/2015/including-release-info-into-war/) by using the `maven-war-plugin`.

Answer (score 29):

Or you can use the **addDefaultImplementationEntries** or **addDefaultSpecificationEntries** flags which will add several entries including the `project.version` property.

**addDefaultImplementationEntries**

```
Implementation-Title: ${project.name}
Implementation-Version: ${project.version}
Implementation-Vendor-Id: ${project.groupId}
Implementation-Vendor: ${project.organization.name}
Implementation-URL: ${project.url}
```

**addDefaultSpecificationEntries**

```
Specification-Title: ${project.name}
Specification-Version: ${project.version}
Specification-Vendor: ${project.organization.name}
```

Default value for both is false. If a property is not defined (e.g. `project.organization.name`), then that line will be excluded from the manifest.

This could go into the **maven-war-plugin** configuration as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -2):

Put `${project.version}` in your manifest.mf where you want the version to be. In order for this to work, I believe you need the resources plugin so that manven will 'filter' resources as they are included in your war file.

Comment: But the manifest file is not a resource. It is generated at build time, correct? If it is generated at build time, then it will not be processed as a resource. Am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Matthew it can be a resource, but it's an incorrect approach. You're right, the file is generated on-fly by maven-war-plugin. Your answer below is correct.