# Maven config to put project version on a file name inside war file to read with 'unzip -l app.war'

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, war

How can I configure my pom file so that maven will automatically build the war including a file named using the project version number, e.g. version-3.1.2.txt ?

This is for ease of use during deployment.

I can't name the war file MyApp-3.1.2.war for various reasons.

If that's not possible, I will have to make do with writing the version number into the manifest like this [How to put maven project version in war file manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780428/how-to-put-maven-project-version-in-war-file-manifest) and working out what the linux cmd to unzip, read and dispose of the manifest file would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}" />
                            <touch file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/version-${project.version}.txt" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>                        
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have created a working example on GitHub: 
https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/stackoverflow-27963488

Comment: great tool to add to maven - a nice way to execute anything I guess without needing to write a plugin. My only slight problem now is that the `prepare-package` phase isn't executed when I run `war:war` but I guess the maven docs will be pretty clear on that. Thanks.

Comment: execute mvn clean package... this will go through the clean and the default lifecycle of maven... with package your execution will stop at the package phase of the default lifecycle.

Comment: here i found a nice introduction to maven lifecycle: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2xWZMH_GZs&spfreload=10